# selecting elements through Selenium is not working

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, iframe, webdriverwait

There are HTML elements on the website (https://www.immowelt.de/expose/2ult44w) that Selenium does not recognize at all. But I would like to be able to address them. I still recognize the element "body" without any problems, however "div [@ class = 'cdk-overlay-container']" is not. Errors are not thrown.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\go2\\installation\\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://www.immowelt.de/expose/2ult44w");
driver.execute_script("return document.readyState") == "complete"
time.sleep(10)

#just so that a message is clicked away:
datenschutz = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[@id='uc-btn-accept-banner']")
if len(datenschutz) > 0: datenschutz[0].click()

#that is not recognized:
example = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='cdk-overlay-container']")
print("Counts:"+str(len(example))) #result: Counts:0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are unable to found it because the element is present inside an `iframe`.

You need to switch to `iframe` first.

To Switch to iframe
Induce `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it`()

And

Induce `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `presence_of_all_elements_located`()

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\go2\\installation\\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://www.immowelt.de/expose/2ult44w")
btn=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[@id='uc-btn-accept-banner']")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", btn)
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID,"externalViewerStage")))
example=WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='cdk-overlay-container']")))
print("Counts:"+str(len(example)))
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```